# How to check if two files exist

Tags: php, codeigniter

On my **install application routes.php** in CodeIgniter I would like to check if two files exist and set them according.

Where, if the files exist then it would be upgraded, else go to step one.

Is there a better and more safer way?

```
$admin = dirname(FCPATH) . '/admin/config/database.php';
$catalog = dirname(FCPATH) . '/catalog/config/database.php';

if (file_exists($admin, $catalog)) {
    $route['default_controller'] = "upgrade/index";
    $route['404_override'] = '';
} else {
    $route['default_controller'] = "step_1/index";
    $route['404_override'] = '';
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

You need to check the file existence separately.

```
if (file_exists($admin) && file_exists($catalog)) {
    $route['default_controller'] = "upgrade/index";
    $route['404_override'] = '';
} else {
    $route['default_controller'] = "step_1/index";
    $route['404_override'] = '';
}
```

You can read on the manual, *[file_exists](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php)*.